# How can accept other token in my Smart Contract?

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, web3js

The token is ERC721 by OpenZeppelin

I'm trying to add USDC payments to my Smart Contract, but I'm having problems.

This is my function to accept token.. but transfer its called by Smart Contract. Dont work...

```
function AcceptPayment(uint32 amount) public {
   tokenUSDC.transfer(address(this), amount * priceCapsule);
   bulkMint(_msgSender(), amount);
}
```

Allowance and approve its working fine, testing with Remix.

New try.. but get: Execution reverted on Remix

```
function AcceptPayment(uint32 amount) public {
   bool success = tokenUSDC.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount * priceCapsule);
   require(success, "Could not transfer token. Missing approval?");
   bulkMint(_msgSender(), amount);
}
```

I can't find a solution to make the transfer from the Smart Contract itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user needs to `approve()` your contract address to pull their tokens. This action needs to be called directly from the user address (on the token contract).

Then you can `transferFrom()` their address to yours.

```
function AcceptPayment(uint32 amount) public {
   bool success = tokenUSDC.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount * priceCapsule);
   require(success, "Could not transfer token. Missing approval?");
   bulkMint(_msgSender(), amount);
}
```

Comment: approve() working fine. Testing with allowance its ok.

Comment: When i try this code have a error: execution reverted

Comment: @JSanchezFDZ That's a generic runtime error message. Check if the user has enough tokens (it's possible to approve more than you currently hold), or if the `bulkMint()` function works correctly (e.g. by commenting it out and testing without it).

Comment: what is tokenUSDC here?

Comment: @RohitMittal It represents a pointer to the USDC contract. You can instantiate it through an interface of the contract and its address. Example: `IERC20 tokenUSDC = IERC20(address(0x123));` where the `IERC20` is an interface that you expect the contract to implement, and `0x123` is the address where the USDC contract is deployed.

Comment: @PetrHejda Can you refer some demo redository for the same? I am new to this and it will be helping.